# ProgressDialog doesn't appear when executing a Thread using AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am a newbie in Android programming so I hope you could help me. I have this `AsyncTask` which is executed through an `OnClickListener` event and inside the `doInBackground()` method, is the `Thread` which is not running on the UI Thread.

`AsyncTask` executed through `OnClickListener`:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
  }
});
```

The `AsyncTask` which is a subclass of the `MainActivity`:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  ProgressDialog progress;

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Show ProgressDialog before the task starts.
    progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progress.setMessage("Running...");
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Since the thread is not running on the UI thread,
    // I have to use the runOnUiThread() method so the
    // app won't crash when the thread is complete.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          new ThreadFromOtherClass(arg1, arg2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Exception", "Something happened.", e);
        }
      }
    });
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    // Hide the dialog when the task ends.
    progress.dismiss();
  }
}
```

I don't get any issues running the `Thread` but the `ProgressDialog` doesn't show during the task execute. However, if I exclude the `runOnUiThread()` method, the dialog appears but the app crashes when the `Thread` completes.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Calling `runOnUiThread()` from `doInBackground()` like that completely defeats the purpose of using an `AsyncTask`. Whatever is crashing is probably a UI update, which you would need to move to `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah but I got no other idea how can I run the `Thread` without any crashing issues...

Comment: @HumblePotatoII, checck the answer i posted using constructor.

Comment: ^ @MikeM. is right about the fact you should NOT use runOnUiThread() in asynctask. still you welcome to post the log when your app crush if you want help with the progress dialog.

Comment: @yotamhadas But I got the app crashing issues when the `Thread` completes. Any other way/idea?

Comment: Please refer to the last sentence of my first comment. If you need specific help, post that `Thread` class.

Comment: @MikeM. It took me some time updating the question, thanks for your patience...

Comment: That's not valid Java. We'll need to see the actual code, and, just to save time, the stack trace from the crash.

Comment: Please wait a moment...

Comment: I may be late, but if you could post the stacktrace when you remove the `runOnUiThread` enclosure, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> ProgressDialog doesn't appear

Create a constructor of `MyAsyncTask` and pass `Context` of `MainActivty`:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
Context context;

public MyAsyncTask(Context context){
  context.this = context;
}

  ProgressDialog progress;

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Show ProgressDialog before the task starts.
    progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progress.setMessage("Running...");
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();
  }
```

Inside onClick:

```
new MyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
```

Comment: How exactly is this going to solve the problem? That is, how is it any different than what the OP already has?

Comment: @MikeM., I'm also sure that `runOnUiThread` has not to be used inside the dackground process inside asynctask, but I simply answered the question of how to display the progressDialog

Comment: The `runOnUiThread()` call is the problem. Not how the `AsyncTask` is getting the `Context`. The thread run there is blocking the UI thread, which is why the `ProgressDialog` doesn't show. Notice the OP mentions that it does show when they remove that call. This won't change anything.

Comment: @MikeM.  I don't think `runOnUiThread()` is the problem. It is not blocking the UI thread. He is actually starting another worker thread from inside there, which will again be executed in the background. Correct me if I'm mistaken :)

Comment: @RobinRex Yeah, I misspoke, there. I really meant "The _code_ run there is blocking the UI thread." I don't believe their `ThreadFromOtherClass` class is actually a `Thread`, despite the name. If you look at the revisions on the question, you'll see they had posted, for a time, what would basically amount to a simple method, though it wasn't valid Java, so I didn't care to pursue it, until we had complete, correct info.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as it should. The problem there is that, you are actually starting another thread from inside `doInBackground()` method (which I really think is not a good idea for whatever reason it may be).

As soon as that second thread is started, you'll get a callback to `onPostExecute()`. Even though the "second" thread might have a lot of work to do, your `MyAsyncTask` is not waiting for it to finish.

So, actually, your dialog is shown and dismissed so fast, that you don't notice it in your screen.